How does 「交換したていで」 mean "say you changed [the oil]"?
In this video and timestamp, a text message reads: 「交換したていで大丈夫です!!」
The provided translation is: "Just tell you them changed [their oil], it'll be fine."
I'm confused how 交換したていで leads to that meaning.  If 「いで」 was 「言って」 instead I could see that, but as is I'm not sure.

てい (often written as 体 or 態) is a noun meaning appearance, but it is often used in a form 体で and somewhat idiomatically means "with the pretense of...", as found in your example. The given translation also makes sense since telling a lie is a common form of pretension, but the original sentence does not limit to it.
